# Spring Integration Expression For Bean References on Application Context

Tags: java, spring, expression, integration

I have a doubt that if is possible to resolve a bean reference for a JMS destination to config a JMS Adapter.

I have several destination configured as follows on Spring:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="BeanID" jndi-name="jms/QUEUE" lazy-init="false"/>
```

Then i put a value on the Message Headers with the value like :

```
@ServiceActivator
public Message<?> sendToJms(Message<?> messageInput){ 
    String queueName = solveQueueName(refToSolveBeanID); 
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(messageInput.getPayLoad()).setHeader("beanIdHeaderRef, queueName ).builder();
}
```

Now my problem is how to construct the expression to solve the bean reference on Spring Context for the following configuration works.

```
<int:chain input-channel="jmsChannel">
        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter  
            connection-factory="solicitacaoConnFactory"   destination-expression="headers.beanIdHeaderRef">
        </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
    </int:chain>
```

as you notice the JMS Destination is configured using the **jndi-lookup** 
i tried some variations but all failed. I thought that is have to pass to the BeanFactory the header value, but have no idea how to create the expression, does anyone know how the expression should look like?

Regards.

Comment: Sorry some typos on code snippet... code was wrote here...

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code I don't see reason to have some access to the `BeanFactory` from the SpEL. You can just resolve your `refToSolveBeanID` to the target `Destination` and place that object to the `headers` directly.

Your SpEL will be the same though.

Comment: Yes, i did that and worked, in fact the jndi lookup will be not necessary, since the destination-expression solves without the need of the JNDI lookup configuraiton.